# Steps to run Java code in Matlab environment?

Tags: java, matlab, apache-commons

I want to run the Java code below in Matlab. 
It ran successfully in JAVA environment.
I am using

> apache-jakarta-commons-net-1.4.1.jar

to run this code.

The software that I use are

```
MATLAB Version 7.7.0.471 (R2008b)
Operating System: Microsoft Windows Vista Version 6.1 (Build 7600)
Java VM Version: Java 1.6.0_04 with Sun Microsystems Inc. 
     Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM  mixed mode
```

My java code is

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.commons.net.TimeTCPClient;// third party class
public final class TimeClient
{

public static final void timeTCP(String host) throws IOException
{
TimeTCPClient client = new TimeTCPClient();
try {
// We want to timeout if a response takes longer than 4 seconds
client.setDefaultTimeout(4000);
client.connect(host);
System.out.println(client.getDate());
}
finally {
client.disconnect();
}
}

public static final void main(String[] args)
{
{
try
{
timeTCP(args[0]);
}
catch (IOException e)
{
e.printStackTrace();
System.exit(1);
}
}

}

}
```

`which timeclient` gave the following error

```
Warning: A Java exception occurred trying to load the TimeClient class:
Java exception occurred:
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: TimeClient : Unsupported major.minor
version 51.0

    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)

    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)

    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)

    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)

    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(Unknown Source)

    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)

    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)

    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)

    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)

    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)

    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)

    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(Unknown Source)

    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)

    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)

    at
    com.mathworks.jmi.OpaqueJavaInterface.findClass(OpaqueJavaInterface.java:470) 
'TimeClient' not found.
```

Comment: Maybe you also need the package name to address your class. What is it?

Comment: Please help  me with steps.In detail please

Comment: There is no package line in your code - maybe you omitted it? Maybe helpful: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_package

Comment: package line is not required .I am using the inbuilt java packages.The code runs successfully outside java.But I don't know to run the code in matlab.

Comment: I suggest that matlab might require package.

Comment: What do you get when typing  `which TimeClient` at the Matlab command prompt? What is the error message you get when trying to use your class file? **Please update (edit) your question** with these answers to have a chance to get help here :-)

Comment: @jonas I have put the Which TimeClient O/p in the question body

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MATLAB is apparently using a different Java version from the one you used to compile your `.jar`. Make sure to compile it with the Java version used inside MATLAB. Since you didn't state how you determined the Java version number given in your question, make sure you call

```
version -java
```

from the Matlab command prompt, and then use that version to compile your `.jar`. More info can be found [here](http://www.java.net/node/664117).

Comment: @ Jonas Java VM Version: Java 1.6.0_04 with Sun Microsystems Inc. 
     Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM  mixed mode

Comment: I installed Java 1.6.0_04 and now no error with ** which Timeclient ** .Please guide me for further steps to run this code    thanks for your effort and prompt reply.

Comment: How am I supposed to know what the remaining problem is? If you don't edit your question to show what is still the problem, no-one on earth can "guide you for further steps"...

Comment: @ Jonas sorry for stupid reply. I want to get this code run like it happens in java.I don't know the command in matlab so that i can run it  from matlab prompt.Or if there is any steps and syntax that i have to follow.

Comment: I am very much thankful to u! Now I can run the code in matlab   thanks                                        saurabh